# making selenium python not reply to the same message in python

Tags: html, selenium, bots

[image]

so im trying to make a facebook messenger bot with python, im trying to detect when a specific text is sent so I used this code

```py
while True:
    if "!spam" in driver.page_source:
        chat("Why spam")
    time.sleep(.5)
```

but after my bot replies it still keeps sending the message I assume this is because the code basically just looks for the word "!spam" in the browser but is there any way I could make it stop replying to the same message? I assume I can do this with some sort of ID system but I have no idea how.

Comment: Pls check whether my answer satisfies ur requirement.

Comment: Just use break. But this doesn't do what you want it to do. It checks everything in the source not just the send. But !spam is so random it might not even appear in everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can use some sort of a `flag variable` in ur code like this:

```
msg_sent = False #This is the flag variable

while msg_sent == False:
    if "!spam" in driver.page_source:
        chat("Why spam")
        msg_sent = True # msg_sent is set to True, so the loop is terminated
    time.sleep(.5)
```

When u use this code, the msg is sent only once. Hope that this helps!

Comment: I have an idea I assume driver.page_source is a list? what if I can just remove it from the table after im done sending the message?

Comment: It needs to be a bit more advanced than that.
What if, during the course of the conversation, "Why spam" would be an appropriate answer again? With this the bot would never send that again, because he already has send it once.
One would need to check if the last message send is "Why spam", or if "Why spam" is an appropriate answer to the last message received.

Comment: Yeah...I agree. Maybe one thing that u can do is to use a function or something to find out whether a new msg has been sent. If yes, then u can check whether it is a spam msg or not and send a reply accordingly.